# How to get the video thumbnail from Dailymotion video from the video id of that video like in youtube?

Tags: php, dailymotion-api

For youtube I use something like this:

```
<img class="video-thumbnail" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo $video_id; ?>/0.jpg" alt="" width="190">
```

where

$video_id is the code of that video from url.

Can I do something similar for Dailymotion videos

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You just need to add an extra `thumbnail` into the link.

**Video URL**

```
https://www.dailymotion.com/video/{video_id}
```

**Thumbnail URL**

```
https://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/{video_id}
```

Comment: @Hassaan It seems to work, however it redirects to some other url, ie: http://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/x54ikm8 becomes http://s1.dmcdn.net/fIYxd/320x240-IEj.jpg

Comment: This was down for 4-5 days but yeah, now its working :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for videos uploaded after 10/01/2019.

Answer (score 15):

Using the Dailymotion API

`https://api.dailymotion.com/video/VIDEO_ID?fields=field1,field2,...`

Replace field1,field2 with

```
thumbnail_large_url (320px by 240px)
thumbnail_medium_url (160px by 120px)
thumbnail_small_url (80px by 60px)
```

This API request does not require any Access Tokens.

Example :
https://api.dailymotion.com/video/xjfn0s?fields=thumbnail_small_url

This HTTP request returns a JSON data with the image link of the video. For processing JSON data check [PHP Manual - JSON Decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

***EDIT***
As suggested by Ravi using
http://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/`video_id`
is pretty straight forward. But different resolution images use the API

Comment: Greets, where can I see, the list of all availible field options, if there is even such place?

Comment: oh, kind of find it, you can just put wrong parameter in field value, and in debug message there is full list of acceptable values

Comment: @MaxYari here https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x26ezrb?fields=thumbnail

Some size properties are thumbnail_360_url, 480, 720

Comment: Theses fields are deprecated : https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#playlist-fields-deprecated

use : https://api.dailymotion.com/video/xjfn0s?fields=thumbnail_url
 as described here -> https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#video-fields

Comment: Like Sami said, theses fields are deprecated. You should now use fields `thumbnail_url` or `thumbnail_360_url` or `thumbnail_720_url` and so on. As described [in dailymotion api documentation](https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#video-fields)

Comment: To get all possible fields, pass some bogus value - will return error with allowed values, ie: https://api.dailymotion.com/video/xjfn0s?fields=will-give-error

Answer (score 5):

```
$id='xwxadz'; // ID DAILYMOTION EXAMPLE
$thumbnail_medium_url='https://api.dailymotion.com/video/'.$id.'?fields=thumbnail_medium_url';
$json_thumbnail = file_get_contents($thumbnail_medium_url);
$get_thumbnail = json_decode($json_thumbnail, TRUE);
$thumb=$get_thumbnail['thumbnail_medium_url'];
echo $thumb; // Output Example : http://s2.dmcdn.net/BJL4o/160x120-mzR.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simpler way for above objective. Suppose following is the url that I want to download thumbnail

http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x17pcar_hadoop-tutorial-how-to-index-and-search-data-with-solr_tech

From this url get last string and
Extract string id

```
x17pcar_hadoop-tutorial-how-to-index-and-search-data-with-solr_tech
```

Now split above string on underscorebasis (_). First one is video id i.e. `x17pcar`

Now run following url using id to get thumbnail

http://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/x17pcar