# How to get thumbnail of dailymotion video using the video ID

Tags: php, dailymotion-api, video-thumbnails

I have reviewed a lot of information, but a working version for the moment not found.

I took the code from this article:
[How to get the video thumbnail from Dailymotion video from the video id of that video like in youtube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173641/how-to-get-the-video-thumbnail-from-dailymotion-video-from-the-video-id-of-that)

```
$id='xwxadz'; // ID DAILYMOTION EXAMPLE
$thumbnail_medium_url='https://api.dailymotion.com/video/'.$id.'?fields=thumbnail_medium_url';
$json_thumbnail = file_get_contents($thumbnail_medium_url);
$get_thumbnail = json_decode($json_thumbnail, TRUE);
$thumb=$get_thumbnail['thumbnail_medium_url'];
echo $thumb; // Output Example : http://s2.dmcdn.net/BJL4o/160x120-mzR.jpg
```

outputs:

```
Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in Z:\home\static.loc\www\new.php on line 4

Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.dailymotion.com/video/xwxadz?fields=thumbnail_medium_url) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No error in Z:\home\static.loc\www\new.php on line 4
```

Comment: Your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444249/unable-to-find-the-wrapper-https-did-you-forget-to-enable-it-when-you-config

Answer (score 0):

Type of thumbnail :

```
url thumbnail_60_url    size : 60px     
url thumbnail_120_url   size : 120px     
url thumbnail_180_url   size : 180px     
url thumbnail_240_url   size : 240px     
url thumbnail_360_url   size : 360px     
url thumbnail_480_url   size : 480px     
url thumbnail_720_url   size : 720px     
url thumbnail_url       size : 86px
```

I have all ready execute this code

**GET Method this url :    https://api.dailymotion.com/video/'+videoID+'?fields=id,thumbnail_url,thumbnail_60_url,thumbnail_120_url,thumbnail_240_url,humbnail_360_url ,thumbnail_480_url ,thumbnail_720_url**