# Links to Dailymotion video thumbnails don't seem to work anymore for new videos

Tags: dailymotion-api

On Dailymotion I used to get the video thumbnails with a link like this (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173641/how-to-get-the-video-thumbnail-from-dailymotion-video-from-the-video-id-of-that))

```
https://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/{video_id}
```

This doesn't seem to work anymore for newly uploaded videos (since 10/01/2019), but still works for videos uploaded before.

Links still working:

```
video:     https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x7ly7gc
thumbnail: https://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/720/video/x7ly7gc
```

Links not working anymore:

```
video:     https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x7m2223
thumbnail: https://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/720/video/x7m2223
```

Is there any other way to get the thumbnails for the new videos without having to make calls to the API before displaying them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only sustainable way to get your thumbnails urls is to use the API.

For example: https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x7m2223?fields=thumbnail_720_url